# Customizing user model and forms in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to set up a custom user using AbstractUser with a couple more added fields, but when I check the add user form in the site admin, the form fields appear in different order (password, groups and user permissions first, then the username, etc.)

In my settings I have registered the AUTH_USER_MODEL to my custom User class. I have a user class with a cople of test fields, when I run it the fields appear in the order specified above. Then I created a CustomUserCreationForm and a CustomUserAdmin to try and order the fields, but then it only ended up showing only user and password.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'bio', 'location', 'birth_date')
```

**admin.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm


admin.site.register(User) #This one shows all the fields scrambled
#admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin) #This one only shows 3 fields on the creation (user, pass and pass_confirm)
```

What I'd like to see is something similar to how the Add user form regularily does it, only with the extra fields I added and ordered correctly.

Thanks in advance for the imput

Comment: But showing three fields initially *is* how the add user form works.

Comment: When you use the default form it shows all the fields in the correct order (username, password, password confirmation, email, super user status and so on), with the CustomUserAdmin it _only_ shows username, password, password confirmation and without it it shows all the fields but in a different order.

What I want to know is if there's a way to use the default that has all the fields in the correct order but with the added fields at the end.